# Unique index for various content in second column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to create unique index for various content in second column?
I mean this situation:

Table1: ID(primary key), CategoryID (must be unique because its relational to Table2 CategoryID), Name, ClientID.

CategoryID 1,2,3 for ClientID 1
CategoryID 1,2,3 for ClientID 2

When it's unique I can't insert 1,2,3 for ClientID 2, but CategoryID need to be unique (relation). Is there any workaround for this situation?

Comment: I think you might need multi-part primary key. Your primary key would be a combination of `CategoryId` and `ClientId`. Your foreign key constraint would still just be `table1.CategoryId` -> `table2.CategoryId`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

Added unique index to columns CategoryID and ClientID in Table1, then made relation with Table2 by adding foreign key to CategoryID in Table2.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Category]
    ON [dbo].[Category]([CategoryID] ASC, [ClientID] ASC);

CONSTRAINT [FK_Product_Category] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryID], [ClientID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([CategoryID], [ClientID]),
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
CREATE TABLE( ... , UNIQUE KEY(ClientID, CategoryID))
```

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Category]
    ON [dbo].[Category]([CategoryID] ASC, [ClientID] ASC);  ?

Comment: Yes, this is the one. Since you didn't specify the exact database you're using, I provided a more general syntax

Comment: Yes, its working, but adding the same entry two times now. I think its because two column uniqueness. How can I repair this?

Comment: You need a UNIQUE index that allows non-unique values? :) Then you don't need the **UNIQUE** index, you need a **non-unique** index. Just drop the word "unique" from the definition (`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ...`)

Comment: Also, check `FOREIGN KEY`'s, I think this is actually what you want.

Comment: No, for the relation you only need to have the `UNIQUE KEY` on the other side (`Table2`). On this side you don't need the unique key. Make sure your relation is in the correct direction. How do you create it?

Comment: I can't add unique key on Table2, because I can't insert anything in Table1 then.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how a unique key on table2 would affect your inserting to table1. Does table1 have a trigger that inserts to table2? Or is your foreign key constraint going the wrong way? Which table is your "lookup" table?